# Rewriting zipWith function using list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, zip, list-comprehension, winghci

I've rewritten the zipWith function using recursion, and now I am trying to rewrite it using list comprehension. I have run into quite a few binding errors and I know that my second line is incorrect. This is the function I have that works like zipWith using recursion:

```
zipW :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] 
zipW _ [] _ = []  
zipW _ _ [] = []  
zipW f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipW f xs ys
```

And this is my attempt to rewrite it as list comprehension:

```
zipW2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipW2 f xs ys = [f x y | (x, y) <- zipW2 f xs ys]
```

I am not sure how to correct the second statement so that it works like zipWith and allows me to choose the operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need [Parallel List Comprehensions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f xs ys = [f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys]
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this will work; I wasn't aware of parallel list comprehension yet. However, I'm trying to import the ParallelListComp statement so it will work in my Haskell window, I use notepad and load the file into WinCHCi. I can't get it to load the file without it breaking on that import statement.

Comment: @T-Bird in ghci you can activate the extension by `:set -XParallelListComp`

Answer (score 2):

The original `zipWith` has three cases:

1. when the first list is empty
2. when the second list is empty
3. when the neither list is empty

The third case recursively calls `zipWith` on the tails of the arguments, which does the case analysis again.

In your definition, you only have one case - the list comprehension, so any recursive calls are going to wrap right back to that. And without case analysis, you could loop forever here:

```
>>> let myZipWith f xs ys = [ f x y | (x,y) <- myZipWith f xs ys ]
>>> myZipWith (,) [] []
^CInterrupted.
```

Furthermore because you're using `f` in the recursive call but requiring that the recursive output be a pair, you're placing the implicit requirement that `f x y` produce a pair:

```
>>> :t myZipWith 
myZipWith :: (t2 -> t3 -> (t2, t3)) -> t -> t1 -> [(t2, t3)]
```

The solution is to not recurse, but instead to consider each pair directly.

You can [use behzad.nouri's solution of enabling the `ParallelListComp` language extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33684292/9859):

```
>>> :set -XParallelListComp
>>> let myZipWith f xs ys = [ f x y | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
>>> myZipWith (+) [1,2,4] [0,10,20]
[1,12,24]
```

`ParallelListComp` makes the second (and later) vertical pipe characters (`|`) in a list comprehension legal syntax, stepping through those lists in parallel (zip-like) with earlier lists.

It's good to know how this differs from normal list comprehensions, where you separate each list you draw from with commas. Using commas does nested iteration which is flattened out in the resulting list:

```
>>> let notZipWith f xs ys = [ f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
>>> notZipWith (+) [1,2,4] [0,10,20]
[1,11,21,2,12,22,4,14,24]
```

[Using the `ParallelListComp` extension is really just syntatical sugar for the original `zipWith`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/ParallelListComp), so you may consider it cheating.

You could also just rely on the original `zip`:

```
>>> let myZipWith f xs ys = [ f x y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys ]
>>> myZipWith (+) [1,2,4] [0,10,20]
[1,12,24]
```

But since `zip` is defined as `zipWith (,)`, that's probably cheating too.

Another way you could go is to use indices:

```
>>> let myZipWith f xs ys = [ f x y | i <- [0..min (length xs) (length ys) - 1], let x = xs !! i, let y = ys !! i ]
>>> myZipWith (+) [1,2,4] [0,10,20]
[1,12,24]
```

But this is going to be horrendously inefficient, as `!!` is a linear-time operation, making `myZipWith` quadratic, while `zipWith` is linear:

```
>>> :set +s
>>> last $ myZipWith (+) (replicate 10000000 1) (replicate 10000000 2)
3
(4.80 secs, 3282337752 bytes)
>>> last $ zipWith (+) (replicate 10000000 1) (replicate 10000000 2)
3
(0.40 secs, 2161935928 bytes)
```

I'm sure there's other bad ways to create an equivalent to `zipWith` with a list comprehension, but I'm not terribly convinced that there's a *good* way, even from the ones above.